# How to set a 3rd party app to open ms-calculator links

Tags: windows, windows-store, calculator

My Microsoft Store and MS Calculator apps (which is a "MS store" app) are broken (don't open at all), and I am done trying to figure out how to fix them (I'm using Windows 10).

I still need the calculator button on my Microsoft keyboard to open a calculator app though (eg. SpeedCrunch).

What I get now when I press the button is an error message, because I uninstalled MS Calc:

> You'll need a new app to open this ms-calculator link

The only option in the dialog is to choose an app from the MS store (which won't work in my case).

**How do I set another .exe to open `ms-calculator` links?**